# Javascript: Passing a function with matches to replace( regex, func(arg) ) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, replace, arguments

According to this site the following replace method should work, though I am sceptical.
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/55-Using-Methods-in-Javascript-Replace-Method.htm

My code is as follows:

```
text = text.replace( 
    new Regex(...),  
    match($1) //$.. any match argument passed to the userfunction 'match',
              //    which itself invokes a userfunction
);
```

I am using Chrome 14, and do not get passed any parameters passed to the function match?

**Update**:

It works when using

```
text.replace( /.../g, myfunc($1) );
```

The JavaScript interpreter expects a *closure*, - apparent userfunctions seem to lead to scope issues i.e. further userfunctions will not be invoked. Initially I wanted to avoid closures to prevent necessary memory consumption, but there are already safeguards.

To pass the arguments to your own function do it like this (wherein the argument[0] will contain the entire match:

```
result= text.replace(reg , function (){
        return wrapper(arguments[0]);
});
```

Additionally I had a problem in the string-escaping and thus the RegEx expression, as follows:

`/\s......\s/g`

is not the same as

`new Regex ("\s......\s" , "g")` or
`new Regex ('\s......\s' , "g")`

so be careful!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by using `text.replace( /.../g, myfunc($1) );`? I believe that actually doesn't work, as `$1` must be in a string.

Comment: See my comment to Joe's answer, and here for an example:  https://github.com/lsauer/KeyBoarder/blob/master/keyboarder.js#L511

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Using a function in there makes sense to me, but expecting `$1` to have a value does not.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

$1 must be inside the string:

```
"string".replace(/st(ring)/, "gold $1") 
// output -> "gold ring"
```

with a function:

```
"string".replace(/st(ring)/, function (match, capture) { 
    return "gold " + capture + "|" + match;
}); 
// output -> "gold ring|string"
```

Comment: yes, in the string $1 is parsed by the replace function.

In the code example $1 is just any variable, taken from the example in the link. 

---
It is best to pass arguments[0] though, because the last argument will contain the entire text.

Comment: Took a bit to wrap my head around, but exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for new RegExp(pattern, modifiers).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: modifiers are sufficient for his case.