# Passing regexp saved value as array index

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace `[link]0[/link]` with `<a href=...`

Now, the links are saved in an array `links` and the number inside `[link][/link]` is the pointer to `links` index.

I am trying to do next:

```
txt.replace( /\[link\](\d+)\[\/link\]/ , "<a href='" + links[ THE_INDEX ][ 0 ] + "' target='_blank'>" + ( links[ THE_INDEX ][ 1 ] || links[ THE_INDEX ][ 0 ] ) + "</a>" );
```

but I don't know, how to pass the saved value. Could you help me solve it?

P.S. I know I could make loop and use the `exec()` to save value and pass it, but I want to know, is it possible to do it like I sayd above.

#### For a more simple example of expectation

```
my_array = [ "data1", "data2", "data3" ];

"xxx1xxx".replace( /xxx(\d+)xxx/, "my_data=" + my_array[ THE_MATCH ] ); // should be "my_data=data1"
"xxx3xxx".replace( /xxx(\d+)xxx/, "my_data=" + my_array[ THE_MATCH ] ); // should be "my_data=data3"
```

Where `THE_MATCH` is taken from the regex match.

Comment: just edited your question to try to remove noise from the example. If you don't like don't hesitate to turn it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
function replacer(str, p1, p2 ){
    return "<a href='" + links[ p1 ] + "'></a>"
}
var newString = "XXzzzz".replace(/(X*)(z*)/, replacer)
```

While the values passed to `replacer()` as p1, p2 are the matched values.
The amount of `p` arguments in `replacer()` needs to be as the amount of matched values.

Comment: Yes.. I was just to say the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192436/javascript-passing-a-function-with-matches-to-replace-regex-funcarg-doesn (duplicated? :))