# jQuery replace multiple words in a string in one go

Tags: jquery, replace

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to output `JAN17`, `FEB18`, `MAR19` but it outputs `JAN19`, `FEB17`, `MAR18`

Can you guys please help me and tell me why it happens?

```js
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {

  var leftContent = $(".leftPart").html().replace("16</dateto>", "17</dateto>").replace("17</dateto>", "18</dateto>").replace("18</dateto>", "19</dateto>");
  var leftContent2 = $(leftContent).text();
  $('.rightPart textarea').val(leftContent2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftPart">
  <pre>
<DateTo> Some text here JAN16</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here FEB17</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here MAR18</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here JAN16</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here FEB17</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here MAR18</DateTo>
</pre></div>
<div class="rightPart">
  <textarea class="policyDetails"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are chaining the [`.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) operations so that they are replacing their own results.

Your easiest option is to reverse the order of the replace operations.

Alternatively, you could combine them all into a single operation and use a regex with a [capture replacement function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7193481/33969).

```js
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
  var leftContent = $(".leftPart").html().replace(/(16|17|18)\<\/dateto\>/g, 
    function (match, capture) {
      return (Number(capture) + 1) + "</dateto>";
    }
  );
  var leftContent2 = $(leftContent).text();
  $('.rightPart textarea').val(leftContent2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftPart">
  <pre>
<DateTo> Some text here JAN16</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here FEB17</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here MAR18</DateTo>
</pre></div>
<div class="rightPart">
  <textarea class="policyDetails"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is I have to use `&lt;/DateTo` instead of `</DateTo>` becuase I has to pass this through XML. Do you know how to implement this code for `&lt;/DateTo`?

Comment: You probably don't need to escape any of the `&lt;` chars, but make sure you keep `\ ` in front of the `/`. [Here's a good online regex tester if you need to play](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: If you wanted to support any number instead of 16, 17, or 18, then you can update the regex to: `/(\d+)\<\/dateto\>/`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated fiddle.

```
<div class="leftPart">
  <pre>
<DateTo> Some text here JAN16</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here FEB17</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here MAR18</DateTo>
</pre></div>
<div class="rightPart">
  <textarea class="policyDetails"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />



$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {
  var leftContent = $(".leftPart").html().replace("18</dateto>", "19</dateto>").replace("17</dateto>", "18</dateto>").replace("16</dateto>", "17</dateto>");

  var leftContent2 = $(leftContent).text();
  $('.rightPart textarea').val(leftContent2);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vkbL9nj7/)

Comment: Thats. But this doesnt work when I have multiples. See this https://jsfiddle.net/vkbL9nj7/1/

Comment: Thats. But this doesnt work when I have multiples. See this https://jsfiddle.net/vkbL9nj7/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a callback with `replace()` and replace everything in one go

```js
$('.policyCopyBtn').click(function() {

  var left = $(".leftPart").html().replace(/(16|17|18|19)\<\/dateto\>/g, function(r) {
    return ((+r.replace(/\D+/g,'')) + 1) + '</dateto>';
  });
  
  var left2 = $(left).text();
  $('.rightPart textarea').val(left2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftPart">
  <pre>
<DateTo> Some text here JAN16</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here FEB17</DateTo>
<DateTo> Some text here MAR18</DateTo>
</pre></div>
<div class="rightPart">
  <textarea class="policyDetails"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="policyCopyBtn" />
```

If you wanted to just increment any date, it would be

```
.replace(/(\d+)\<\/dateto\>/g,  ...
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cdtk9mz8/)