# Find numbers in a TEXT, and add a specific number to each number you find

Tags: sql, language-agnostic

I have to create a long SQL expression, where I work with Dates in Double format.

For example

SELECT II.Amount from IssuedInvoices II where II.DocDate>=44000 and II.DocDate<=44030

For the project that I am creating, it would save me hours to get a script in any programming language than finds number 44000 and adds 365 to it and then it finds 44030 and adds 365 to it.

I give the script the SQL expression and the script would find all numbers in the SQL expression and add a specific number to each number it finds and then the return value would be the updated SQL expression.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I think the OP wants a string replacement algorithm, where all numeric values in a literal string are replaced with a new number (... i.e., all the numbers having 365 added to them). Assume the actual string must be much longer than the sample Sql string provided.

Comment: But it may be useful to look into a better way to write your "long sql expression" without these hard-coded dates...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapped regular expression. An example in Python:

```py
import re

old_query = "SELECT II.Amount from IssuedInvoices II where II.DocDate>=44000 and II.DocDate<=44030"
new_query = re.sub('[0-9]+', lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 365), old_query)
print(new_query)
```

outputs

```
SELECT II.Amount from IssuedInvoices II where II.DocDate>=44365 and II.DocDate<=44395
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19737653/9997212) the Java version and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7192436/9997212) the Javascript version.